# Xamarin (forms) iOS Entity Framework migration issue - no key on entity (it is) error

Tags: c#, ios, entity-framework, xamarin

In the constructor of my DbContext, the call to Database.Migrate is failing telling me that my entity doesn't have a primary key (it does, I am using the Key attribute)

Initially this was when I was updating an existing app but I have deleted the database and its still happening.  (the Migrate should create the DB if its not there).

This is only a problem on iOS - on Android the migration takes, no problem.

**EDIT: I've gone back to a previous commit that I know works (its in the app store! and that didn't have any problems) - and I'm now getting the exception on that version too - also, I copied the project onto another machine (with an older version of VS) and when I debug on the phone it throws the exception there too)**

The config looks like this:

```
public class Config
{
    [Key]
    public int ConfigID { get; set; }

    public string Token { get; set; }

    public string DeviceIdentifier { get; set; }
}
```

The migrations are as follows (but I don't think it actually gets as far as the migrations, could be wrong)

```
public partial class InitialMigration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Configs",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ConfigID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                Token = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Configs", x => x.ConfigID);
            });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Configs");
    }
}
```

And:

```
public partial class DiagnosticsAdded : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Diagnostics",
            columns: table => new
            {
                DiagnosticID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                Key = table.Column<string>(nullable: true),
                Value = table.Column<string>(nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Diagnostics", x => x.DiagnosticID);
            });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropTable(
            name: "Diagnostics");
    }
}
```

Finally:

```
public partial class DeviceIdentifierAdded : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
            name: "DeviceIdentifier",
            table: "Configs",
            nullable: true);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "DeviceIdentifier",
            table: "Configs");
    }
}
```

The Model Builder (includes the Key!)

```
protected override void BuildModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
        modelBuilder
            .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "3.1.16");

        modelBuilder.Entity("Mobile.Models.Config", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("ConfigID")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                b.Property<string>("DeviceIdentifier")
                    .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                b.Property<string>("Token")
                    .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                b.HasKey("ConfigID");
                
                b.ToTable("Configs");
            });

        modelBuilder.Entity("Mobile.Models.Diagnostic", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("DiagnosticID")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("INTEGER");

                b.Property<string>("Key")
                    .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                b.Property<string>("Value")
                    .HasColumnType("TEXT");

                b.HasKey("DiagnosticID");

                b.ToTable("Diagnostics");
            });
```

#pragma warning restore 612, 618
}

Comment: Try to raise your issue on [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues) for better support .  And as a suggestion , for database operation in mobile development [SQLite.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows) is a better choice .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied in the link settings, its was set to "Link All" - when I changed this to "Link Framework SDK's Only" it works fine.

Comment: If problem has been solved could you mark it as answer ?